# C#_ASP.NET-Oracle Data Adapter in ASP.NET cannot handle huge data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm using OracleDataAdapter class to execute the stored procedure and fill the result to dataset. It work fine with 10000 rows, but when the result contains 16000 rows, my code runs forever, it doesn't throw any exceptions. What's happend? This is my code:

```
 try
        {
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectDatabase.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "PKG_DVKH_BAOCAO_EVNSPC.SP_GET_BAOCAO_CDIEN_HAP";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DONVI", OracleType.VarChar).Value = ma_dviqly;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TUNGAY", OracleType.VarChar).Value = tungay;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DENNGAY", OracleType.VarChar).Value = denngay;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_LOAIHS", OracleType.Number).Value = loaihs;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TINHTRANG", OracleType.Number).Value = tinhtrang;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_LOAI_TRAM", OracleType.VarChar).Value = loai_tram;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DS", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        cmd.Transaction.Commit();
                        return ds;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
```

Comment: Why do you use a transaction when you select data? Does the procedure also execute any DML?

Comment: Looks like you use the "Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle", this has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for many years. You should use the Oracle providers: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

Comment: As you can see here, this code will call the stored procedure which return a cursor contains data, and i will fill it in dataset. When i execute the stored directly in Toad Oracle, it runs very fast, but when i call it in the code like this, it stuck. If using ODAC like your suggestions, how can i change this code?

Comment: Do you also fetch the data when you run rhe procedure in Toad?

Comment: In order to use the Oracle Data Provider you have to use namespace `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` instead of `System.Data.OracleClient`

Comment: Yes, the stored procudre has a line which fetch the data from cursor to variable and insert in a temporary table.But when i execute directly the store, it takes 5mins, when i run it in code, it runs forever

Comment: Please show us the code of procedure `PKG_DVKH_BAOCAO_EVNSPC.SP_GET_BAOCAO_CDIEN_HAP`

Comment: It's impossible for me to upload the whole code, because it's too long and compilcated, but it does have the insert and update process